# Passthrough in Virtualhost not preserving the previous URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

- I have a RewriteRule written at Apache to redirect to TOMCAT.
- Passthrough [PT] doesn't seems to work and Getting Bad Request.
- Same configuration works with [P], but I don't want tomcat PORT to be visible in the browser.
- If I enable ProxyPreserve On, I am getting multiple redirect. Following is the virtualhost configuration in my custom.conf file, included in httpd.conf,

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName xyz
>     ServerAlias example.com
>     RewriteEngine On
>     RewriteRule ^(/web) http://IPaddr:8182 [R=301,L]
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
>     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:8080 [PT]
>     #ProxyPreserveHost On
>     #ProxyRequests On
> </VirtualHost>
> ```